# html-webpack-plugin output html , interior body empty

Tags: node.js, webpack

use html-webpack-plugin output html page , but in output page lost body inner html element , like `<div id="app"></div>` , here is my input output and webpack.config file :

### input

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="static/pic/logo.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/weui/weui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/index.css">
    <title>APP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="./dist/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="./dist/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SPA</title>
  <link href="/dist/style.df241090c6a9e0a6bf26.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/vendor.df241090c6a9e0a6bf26.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/app.df241090c6a9e0a6bf26.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

### part webpack.config.js

```
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

    plugins: [
        new htmlWebpackPlugin({
            title:'SPA',
            filename: 'assets/index.html'
        })
    ],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `filename` option is simply used as the output file, it won't read and modify the existing file, if one exists. Because if it did that, every new build would just append to it, unless you cleaned it manually. To use your input as the base, you need to use it as a `template`.

```
new htmlWebpackPlugin({
    title:'SPA',
    filename: 'assets/index.html',
    template: 'path/to/template/index.html'
})
```

The template should not be the same as the output filename, otherwise it gets overwritten. See also [Writing Your Own Templates](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates). The template can be a regular HTML file and it will inject the necessary assets.